# React Router v2.4 { queryKey: false } no longer works

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've updated `react-router` to the latest version - `2.4.1`
I use hashHistory in my app

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
// useRouterHistory creates a composable higher-order function
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })
<Router history={appHistory}/>
```

And now I'm getting an error

```
Warning: Using { queryKey: false } no longer works. 
Instead, just don't use location state if you don't want a key in your URL query string
```

How can I fix this?

I don't want additional query key to appear in url. I expect the same behaviour as from angular router or backbone router.

Comment: can you not just remove the `({ queryKey: false })` part from your code?

Comment: It's definitely an option. But it looks ugly =)

Comment: Ehh, what? :) That's what the error says, and that's what you should do.

Comment: So is there any way to use `hashHistory` without this query key?

Comment: I believe this should work: `const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory);`

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning does not actually originate from React Router but the [history module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) it uses. In fact, the latest version (3.0.0, May 30 2016) doesn’t work at all with React Router:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: You have provided a history object created with history v3.x. This version of React Router is not compatible with v3 history objects. Please use history v2.x instead.

This warning is present [as of v2.5.1](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/commit/44b3c6e996fb23131cdc737604d545a81ccbf9a4) (Jun 24 2016).

So the easiest solution is to just use the same version React Router uses, courtesy of its `package.json`:

```
"history": "^2.0.1"
```

After that, the `queryKey` option works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const history = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)();` but then the refresh or back button will result in white page. It works very similar to `browserHistory` which requires mod_rewrite or middleware to function properly.

Maybe someone knows why they changed it like this because for me it doesn't make sense.

Comment: But in v2.0 it worked fine with `queryKey: false` and back button worked as well

Comment: Yeah... Well, it was the whole point using {queryKey: false} to be able to navigate back and forward and to refresh. So, not really helping.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)();
```